# Connect data points in the order they were individually plotted - matplotlib

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot, line

I am trying to connect points which are plotted individually, but I want to connect them in the order they are plotted. I have a list of numbers referring to a set of points (ordered pairs). The list tells what order the points should be plotted in.

The points are in a dictionary `P`. So let's say `P[1]`, `P[2]`, `P[3]`.  Then `list = (2, 1, 3)`.  I want to plot it so that a line connects `P[2]` to `P[1]` to `P[3]`.  Where `P[i] = (x, y)` is some tuplet with x-coordinate `x` and y-coordinate `y`.

As I have it now, I am plotting the points using a loop.  This works, but it doesn't connect the points.  Any help would be great!  Thanks.

```
x=[-4, 2, -1, 5]
y=[-3, -2, 4, 2]
n = 3 #number of cities

P = dict()
P_0 = (x[0],y[0])

for i in range (1,n):
    P[i] = (x[i],y[i])

route = (2,1,3)
plt.plot([P_0[0]],[P_0[1]])
for k in range (0,n-1):
    plt.plot([P[route[k]][0]],[P[route[k]][1]])
```

Comment: Sorry, n should be equal to 4, not 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the x coordinates as a list and the y coordinates as a separate list, when calling plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[-4, 2, -1, 5]
y=[-3, -2, 4, 2]

plt.plot(x,y,'b-')
```

Comment: This causes the line to connect in the wrong order though.  Is there a way to rearrange the order of the points in the list itself.  But supposing I have many points, I cannot do them manually.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a suitable solution.

```
xnew=[x[i] for i in route]
ynew=[y[i] for i in route]

plt.plot(x,y)
```